# How to grab URL from string with specified alt tags

Tags: c#, regex, string, extract

I would like to extract "http://www.somewebsite.com/wanted.jpg" from the string below where `alt` is set to `"thumbnail"`, and avoid grabbing `http://www.somewebsite.com/notwanted.jpg` :

```
<span>Some information here
  <div> 
    <img src="http://www.somewebsite.com/notwanted.jpg" width="15" height="15" alt="emoticon"> 
    <img src="http://www.somewebsite.com/wanted.jpg" alt="thumbnail"> 
  </div>
</span>
```

What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: The easiest way?  HTML Agility Pack or a similar HTML parser - *not* RegEx.

Comment: @tim I would but this is part of a string from an RSS feed that HTMLagility pack can't process because it's XML based.  I tried and couldn't make it work.

Comment: Ah...another alternative might be to look at LINQ-to-XML, and parse it that way - unless this particular part of the feed is CDATA.  But in this case a RegEx *might* actually be more appropriate, if there's no way to get HTML or XML parsers to work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all the warnings about parsing html with regex, this C# regex will match the url you want:

```
(?<=src=")[^"]+(?="[^">]*?alt="thumbnail")
```

See [demo](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=4aa8c730-e69c-4a79-99b3-6e700fc43899).

**To test it in C#:**

```
var myRegex = new Regex("(?<=src=\")[^\"]+(?=\"[^\">]*?alt=\"thumbnail\")");
string resultString = myRegex.Match(s1).Value;
Console.WriteLine(resultString);
```

**Output:**

> http://www.somewebsite.com/wanted.jpg

**Explanation**

- The lookbehind `(?<=src=")` asserts that what precedes is `src="`
- `[^"]+` matches all chars that are not a `"` (that's what we want)
- The lookahead `(?="[^">]*?alt="thumbnail")`asserts that what follows is a quote, and any chars that are not a quote or a `>` followed by `alt="thumbnail"

---

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: That works, but I had to change it to be 'Groups[0]' :)

Comment: +1 for detailed explanation and clearly warning of awful idea to parse XML/HTML with regex...

Comment: @ChrisL That must have been a small typo, thanks. :) You don't actually need `Groups[0]`, `myRegex.Match(s1).Value;` will do.

Comment: Thanks, see you next time. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below regex to get the img src where `alt` is set to `thumbnail`,

```
\"[^\"]*\"(?=\s*alt=\"thumbnail\")
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oO0cX1)

If you don't want the double quotes present in the output the you could try the below regex,

```
\"\K[^\"]*(?=\"\s*alt=\"thumbnail\")
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zV0gC3)

**Explanation:**

- `\"\K` \K discards the previously matched characters, in our case it discards the previous `"` mark.
- `[^\"]*` Matches any character not of double quotes zero or moretimes.
- `(?=\"\s*alt=\"thumbnail\")` A positive lookahead is used to check that  the string immediately follows after `"` must be `"\s*alt="thumbnail"`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your string is in `htmlText` you can easily load it with HtmlAgilityPack and than perform select:

```
 HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
 html.LoadHtml(htmlText);
 var src = html.DocumentNode
     .SelectSingleNode("//img[@alt='thumbnail']").GetAttributeValue("src","");
```

Comment: This would be my preferred way, but it couldn't get it to load the XML feed -- it would just crash.

Comment: @ChrisL: side note - it looks like there is almost zero information in your question about your actual issue. Your sample shows plain HTML, but comments mention some sort of XML that you can't load. Maybe your real problem is trying to read invalid "XML" or not knowing how to get inner XML of particular node?